# crear base de datos con las propiedades de otra base de datos en SQL es decir (usuarios, roles y tablas)

Tags: sql

Hola quiero crear una base de datos el cual debe contener las propiedades de otra base de datos.
Ejemplo:
si tengo una base de datos llamado base2022 quiero hacer una base similar llamada base2023

Comment: Buenas Erick, te recomiendo mirar [cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Entre otras cosas, te falta proporcionar más detalles como cuál es el problema, qué has intentado o una imagen/código de tu SQL para hacernos a la idea

Comment: O sea.. queres clonar una db?

Comment: Si, en parte quiero clonar una base datos, aunque solo sus esquemas y tablas sin la data que contiene la base clonada

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es generar los scripts por medio de Management Studio. Solo tienes que hacer click derecho sobre la base de datos, seleccionar tareas (Tasks) y Generar Scripts...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso obtendrás un cuadro de diálogo desde el cual puedes seleccionar los objetos que quieras copiar (hay una opción de todos).

En la selección de opciones, no olvides revisar las opciones avanzadas que pueden ser importantes para saber que se va a generar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que se genera el script, solo tienes que cambiar el nombre de la base de datos (y sus archivos) por el nombre de la nueva base de datos. Una vez que hayas hecho las modificaciones, puedes ejecutar el script en la instancia que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información Luis Cazares, funcionó.